# Wait for get request - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I get a **GET request** and I would like to wait for a response to run **code** how do i do this?

My code

```
valid()
{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: "get" }); 
    return this.http.get(this.urlstring+ "getisvalid" , options ).toPromise().then(response => response.json());
}

//Code that is in the function

     this._service.valid().then(resut => this.resut = resut);
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What's the problem with the posted code?

Answer (score 1):

When you subscribe to an observable, you can provide a callback function; in the example below, I call it `CompleteValidCall`.  `CompleteValidCall()` will only be invoked on a successful get that returns data and not an error.  You place whatever follow on logic you need in the callback function.

```
this._service.valid()
   .subscribe(
      result => this.result = result,
      error => this.error = error,
      () => this.CompleteValidCall()
);

completeValidCall() {
  // the rest of your logic here - only executes on obtaining result.
}
```

Comment: The code does answer the question and clearly shows the solution.  I've added a brief description to satisfy you.

Comment: Should that be `() => this.CompleteValidCall`?  You don't want to invoke it at that point.  And (I don't know Angular, I just got pointed here by Review) does the callback get given any arguments?  E.g. to tell it which observable triggered it, and/or the new value?

Comment: No, the code is correct as typed.  Why are you involved in this if you don't know angular?

Answer (score 0):

this.http.get return Observable, so you have to subscribe to it. if you change valid() to:

```
valid() {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: "get"}); 
  return this.http.get(this.urlstring+ "getisvalid" , options ).map(response => response.json());
}
```

then use:

```
this._service.valid().subscribe(resut => this.resut = resut);
```